# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I recently built a new desktop PC and I've been having trouble getting bluetooth working. Previously it was running, but not pairing to headphones. Occasionally it did pair but the sound was choppy, and it would not remember the device and so pairing was very inconsistent. In trying to fix it today I updated bluez and blueman and now I have a new problem; bluetooth won't start at all.

When I try to run blueman-manager, I now get the following error:

> blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting
> blueman-manager 11.02.18 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
> blueman-manager 11.02.18 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting

Bluetooth is definitely enabled in my BIOS. Some other commands and outputs:

$ systemctl | grep -i blue

> sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.2-0000:01:00.0-usb1-1\x2d5-1\x2d5:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device                  loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0
> sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                                                    loaded active     plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0
> bluetooth.service                                                                                              loaded active     running   Bluetooth service
> bluetooth.target                                                                                               loaded active     active    Bluetooth

$ systemctl status bluetooth.service

> bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
> Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-07-12 10:58:21 PDT; 1min 0s ago
> Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)    Main PID: 935 (bluetoothd)
> Status: "Running"
> Tasks: 1 (limit: 77003)
> Memory: 2.5M
> CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
> └─935 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
>
> Jul 12 10:58:21 mfenton-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth
> service... Jul 12 10:58:21 mfenton-desktop bluetoothd[935]: Bluetooth
> daemon 5.53 Jul 12 10:58:21 mfenton-desktop systemd[1]: Started
> Bluetooth service. Jul 12 10:58:21 mfenton-desktop bluetoothd[935]:
> Starting SDP server Jul 12 10:58:21 mfenton-desktop bluetoothd[935]:
> Bluetooth management interface>

$ rfkill list

> 0: hci0: Bluetooth    Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 1: phy0:
> Wireless LAN  Soft blocked: yes   Hard blocked: no

$  dmesg | grep -i blue

> [    4.727839] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22 [    4.727888] Bluetooth: HCI
> device and connection manager initialized [    4.727897] Bluetooth:
> HCI socket layer initialized [    4.727899] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket
> layer initialized [    4.727901] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer
> initialized [    6.753335] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
> [    6.753350] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information
> failed (-110) [    8.250133] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver
> 1.3 [    8.250135] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast [    8.250142] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized [   25.583181] audit: type=1107 audit(1626112719.120:50): pid=941 uid=103
> auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED"
> operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/"
> interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager"
> member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=2501
> label="snap.skype.skype" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Opened a question on the same issue. Did you find a solution to your problem?